# angularjs: Intermediate representation of a model for view and keeping it in sync

Tags: angularjs

I have the following model:

```
{  
    "RU": {
         name: "value a",
         other_key: "xxx",
    }, 
    "EN": {
         name: "value a",
         other_key: "xxx",
    }, 
    ... 10+ other languages ...
}
```

To render form I went with intermediate format:

```
[  
    { name: "value_a", languages: ["RU", "EN"] }
    ... other groups by value ...
]
```

How do I keep this all in sync? Changes in the original model may occur and
I should push them into intermediate format to update view. Changes in the
view may be made by a user and I should propagate them to the model and
intermediate view.

Can not think of good solution without tons of watchers and complicated code.
Ideas?

Comment: Make the model a real object, with methods that do the updates, so they can update the different formats. Also then, the intermediate formats could stay in the model too ...

Comment: Maybe must be watch, you need sync ,you need know change,you need looking or listening when it change

Answer (score 0):

You will only to watch the model & the intermediate format ( do full watch with 3rd parameter set as true - deep watch ).

```
var surpressWatchmodel = false;
var surpressWatchinter = false;

$scope.$watch('model',function(newval,oldval){
  if(surpressWatchmodel) { surpressWatchmodel = false; return; }
      //update intermediate format.
    surpressWatchinter = true;
},true);

$scope.$watch('intermediate',function(newval,oldval){
    if(surpressWatchinter ) { surpressWatchinter = false; return; }
      //update model format.
    surpressWatchmodel= true;
},true);
```

for view you will use ng-model="intermediate.name" ( angular will add this as a watch item for you ).

Comment: Have you tried watchers that can be surpressed in a production application? I'm afraid that the surpression on the model watcher can mask an external change.

Comment: Supression is needed to prevent circular watch.